# Interrupt question ARM?

Tags: microcontroller, c, arm, interrupts

I often see something like this `void UART2_IRQHandler(void) __irq`, and I wonder why __irq is used when declaring interrupt handler, is it required or handler can work without it?

Comment: It is instruction to compiler. Have a look at Assembly code generated with and without __irq... Lot of interesting things happen due to __irq (which are explained in the answers)

Comment: An issue i faced when i omitted the __irq to my Handler was that, when I rentered my ISR Handler for the second time(first time worked well), it changed the mode to IRQ but never called my ISR Handler. When I tried with __irq, it worked well for the second call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, an interrupt service routine written in C is simply a function that takes no arguments and doesn't return anything `void someKindOfIsr(void)`.

`__irq` is a C language extension for your compiler that is used to generate special entry and/or exit assembly instructions for handling interrupts.  For instance, the return instruction may be different if you are returning from an interrupt rather than a simple function to clear some type of interrupt status register.

Whether it is necessary or not depends on what ARM architecture you are working with.  A quick way to find out if it is necessary for your platform is to examine the assembly produced both with and without the `__irq` keyword.

Even if the listing file is exactly the same both with and without the `__irq` keyword, you may want to consider leaving the `__irq` keyword in place for clarity and for portability to some future platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I know what is the purpose of __irq.

Answer (score 5):

Some microcontrollers require a different handling of the stack and return for interrupt handling functions as for normal functions.

For ARM controllers a normal entry to a subroutine uses a PUSH to save stuff on the stack, and on exit of the subroutine you would POP the saved state back and leave the subroutine. ([ARM Assembly Reference page 65](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0489f/DUI0489F_arm_assembler_reference.pdf#page=65))

For an exception handler on modern ARM platforms the state is automatically pushed on the stack, so the compiler doesn't need to create a PUSH instruction on function entry. Also the exit from a exception handler can look different from a normal one, the ARMv7-M architecture will return from an exception if either POP/LDM, LDR or BX will load a value of `0xFXXXXXXX` into the program counter (PC).

So the `__irq` tells the compiler that this functions entry and exit might require special treatment, and special depending on the set target (for 8051 I think there was RET for normal return and RETI for interrupt return).

Answer (score -3):

No, it cant work without _irq. it's a general format. you need to follow this. otherwise it wont work.

Comment: This is a bit thin for an answer. Can you explain exactly what `__irq` does in the compiler?